# Xcode- different Time Conversion to UTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

My Time local time String is **2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30**, And i need to convert the same time to different zone as **2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:30** then want to convert this same time **2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:3**0 to UTC as **2014-12-20 14:00:00** as string.

```
NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df2.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
[df2 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

[df2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timezonename]];
 start_date=[df2 stringFromDate:datepick.date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timezonename]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:start_date];

NSLog(@"Date: %@--%@",start_date, dte);
```

Please help on this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I need to convert local to another time zone with out changing the time as 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30 and 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:30 then to utc

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this Code . might be it helpful for you.

```
NSDate sourceDate = Yourdate;

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"];

NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; // your device time . you can also change any time zone like above.

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];

NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
```

Comment: getting sourcedate as UTC Time

Comment: what you want to say ? please says in detail so that I able to give you relevant answer.

Comment: I need to convert local to another timezone(different Time zones) without changing the time as 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30 and 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:30 then to utc as 2014-12-20 14:00:00 +000..

Comment: so what change source time zone as [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] and destination time zone as you want like [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"].

Comment: I think may be you are confuse between source timeZone and Destination timeZone. if it is then source time zone is the time zone which you want to convert with destination timeZone.

Hope i might be clear from my side.

Comment: i need three timezones as local time ---- another time zone---UTC time

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSDate*)convertThisDate:(NSDate*)aDate
           toThisTimeZone:(NSString*)timeZoneAbbreviation{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *yourDate = [NSDate date];

    NSString *yourDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:timeZoneAbbreviation]];

    NSDate *convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateAsString];


    NSLog(@"convertedDate : %@",convertedDate);

    return convertedDate;

}

//For Local Timezone
-(NSDate*)convertThisDateToLocalTimeZone:(NSDate*)aDate{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *yourDate = [NSDate date];

    NSString *yourDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];//current local time zone in device

    NSDate *convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateAsString];


    NSLog(@"convertedDate : %@",convertedDate);

    return convertedDate;

}
```

**Usage:**

```
    NSDate *UTCDate = [self convertThisDate:myDate
                             toThisTimeZone:@"UTC"];

    NSDate *GMTDate = [self convertThisDate:myDate
                             toThisTimeZone:@"GMT"];

    NSDate *ESTDate = [self convertThisDate:myDate
                             toThisTimeZone:@"EST"];

    //For Local Timezone
    NSDate *localTimeZoneDate = [self convertThisDateToLocalTimeZone:myDate];
```

**To get the list of supported abbreviation, you can do NSLog the time zone list as**

```
NSLog(@"TimeZone List: %@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);

TimeZone List: {
    ADT = "America/Halifax";
    AKDT = "America/Juneau";
    AKST = "America/Juneau";
    ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
    AST = "America/Halifax";
    BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
    BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BST = "Europe/London";
    CAT = "Africa/Harare";
    CDT = "America/Chicago";
    CEST = "Europe/Paris";
    CET = "Europe/Paris";
    CLST = "America/Santiago";
    CLT = "America/Santiago";
    COT = "America/Bogota";
    CST = "America/Chicago";
    EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
    EDT = "America/New_York";
    EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EST = "America/New_York";
    GMT = GMT;
    GST = "Asia/Dubai";
    HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
    HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
    ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
    IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
    IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
    JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
    KST = "Asia/Seoul";
    MDT = "America/Denver";
    MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
    MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
    MST = "America/Denver";
    NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
    NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
    PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
    PET = "America/Lima";
    PHT = "Asia/Manila";
    PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
    PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
    SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
    UTC = UTC;
    WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
    WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
}
```

Comment: I need to convert local to another timezone(different Time zones) without changing the time as 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30 and 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:30 then to utc..

Comment: we didn't change the time,time differs to place to place. so just make use of the above two methods as u needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` from `NSTimeZone` and set the `timezone` for `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

// For GMT + 2.30, seconds will be 7200 (2 hours) + 1800 (30 minutes)
// For GMT + 5.30, seconds will be 18000 (5 hours) + 1800 (30 minutes)
// 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 5 hours + 60 seconds * 30 minutes
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:19800];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:dateString]; 
NSString *newTimeZoneDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",newTimeZoneDateString1);
```

Comment: I need to convert local to another timezone(different Time zones) without changing the time as 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+5:30 and 2014-12-20 16:30:00 GMT+2:30 then to utc. not only +5.30..